# Woocommerce add extra price in PHP

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to add an extra number (extra percentage) to the product price. I get the price of the product. (It works)

```
$price = $product->get_price_html();
```

Then, it is not working.

```
$numberToAdd = ($price / 100) * 20;
$newNumber = $price + $numberToAdd;
echo $newNumber;
```

I can't see the mistake.
Thanks.

**SOLVED**

```
$price = $product->get_price_html(); // Output: From: xx€ string(xxx)
$price = $product->get_price(); // Output: xx
```

You should use the second line if you want to use operators.

Comment: did you checked `var_dump($price);` after this line:- `$price = $product->get_price_html();`?what it says? show us.

Comment: It writes: "From: 65 €" string(188)", I think I get the price from the wrong way :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: is the price integer? try to type cast it to int before doing any operation with it

Comment: @TunaZenginbaş  use `get_price()` .check my answer

Answer (score 0):

First I think you have to see if the value is set. So use `echo $product->get_price_html();` or `var_dump($product->get_price_html());`

Next try to cast to float, so `var_dump($price + floatval(($price / 100) * 20));`

Anyway in the logic I don't see any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to type cast this variable into integer to do any mathemeatical operation into it, it is string by default.

```
$price = (int) $product->get_price_html();
```

you can do mathematical operation with $price now